# Using Delphi and TINetHttp, why do I get a TINetHttp redirect exception with one url but not another?

Tags: delphi, redirect, wininet

Please can someone explain what is happening in the following situation?
It is that one ISP is redirecting a URL but the other one isn't or is something different going on?

I'm using Delphi's TINetHttp (a wrapper arount WinInet) to log onto cpanel on an ISP and recover the session code. I utilise the callback method of TINetHttp to get the redirected URL from which I can extract the session code. With one ISP the code works correctly, but with another the callback gives the exception `Error 12168 - The HTTP redirect request must be confirmed by the user` and the glboal var NewURL is set to an empty string

Assume the URL to logon is `https://MyServer.net:2083/login/?user=username&pass=password` and  INetHttp flNoAutoRedirect flag set to FALSE, so redirects are allowed.Then the following will get the session code from one ISP

```
var
NewURL : string;
url:= 'https://MyServer.net:2083/login/?user=username&pass=password'
RunWebPageCode(url, true);  //navigate to the logon page, INetHttp callback sets NewURL to the redirected url
SessionID := ExtractBetween(NewURL , '/cpsess', '/frontend');  //get the session code from the redirected url
```

Here the INetHttp callback is called and sets global var NewURL to the redirected URL (something like
`https://MyServer.net:2083/cpsess1111633888/frontend/x3/index.html?login=1&post_login=9962390421682`)
from which I extract the session code from between  `/cpsess` and `/frontend`.

With a different ISP, with an almost identical (and correct) url, differing only in the domain name, and INetHttp1 flNoAutoRedirect flag still set to FALSE the INetHttp callback generates the exception 12168 and NewURL is set to an empty string.

However, with both ISPs, if I set  flNoAutoRedirect flag set to TRUE, so the INetHttp callback is not called, I can instead extract the session ID from the html of the blank page that I land on which will look something like

`<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh"CONTENT="2;URL=/cpsess1796422993/frontend/paper_lantern/index.html login=1&amp;post_login=99510958918744"></head><body></body></html>`

so the following code works for both ISPs (if flNoAutoRedirect flag set to TRUE)

```
url:= 'https://MyServer.net:2083/login/?user=username&pass=password'
RunWebPageCode(url, true);  //navigate to the logon page
page := GetWebPageText(url, true);    /get the html of the landing page
SessionID := ExtractBetween(page, '/cpsess', '/frontend');
```

The full code of the various functions are below in case it helps.

```
var
NewURL : string;

procedure Tjhm.RunWebPageCode(TheURL: string; secure: Boolean);
begin
 try
    try
    if secure then
       INetHttp1.Flags := INetHttp1.Flags + [flSecure]
    else
       INetHttp1.Flags := INetHttp1.Flags - [flSecure];
    INetHttp1.Verb := vePost;
    INetHttp1.Url := TheURL ;
    INetHttp1.Open;
    INetHttp1.OpenRequest;
    INetHttp1.SendRequest;
    except
     on E : Exception do
     begin
     showmessage ('error running web page code  +slinebreak
                +  'Exception class name = '+E.ClassName+ slinebreak
                +  'Exception message = '+E.Message);
      end  //on E
     end;
 finally
    INetHttp1.Close;
 end;
 end;

procedure Tjhm.INetHttp1Callback(Sender: TObject; Status: Integer;   Information: Pointer; InformationLength: Integer);
const
  INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT = 110; //a constant in WinInet but redefined here for clarity
begin
if Status = INTERNET_STATUS_REDIRECT then  //we have been redirected
    begin
    newURL := PAnsiChar(Information); // put new url into global var, typecast as 'Information' is a pointer to a non unicode char string
    end;
end;

function Tjhm.ExtractBetween(const Value, A, B: string): string;
{utility to get the text between two delimiters}
var
  aPos, bPos: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  aPos := Pos(A, Value);
  if aPos > 0 then begin
    aPos := aPos + Length(A);
    bPos := PosEx(B, Value, aPos);
    if bPos > 0 then begin
      result := Copy(Value, aPos, bPos - aPos);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a POST request returns a 307 status code, WinInet doesn't do the automatic redirect and returns error 12168 instead.

So I guess your first ISP returns an old 302 code while the other returns a 307.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for the complete list of HTTP redirect codes.

Comment: Thanks, I did already have that list but was looking for a 110 ( Debug showed it getting lots of codes, eventually a 110. So is the method that works for both, setting flNoAutoRedirect flag set to TRUE and looking at the html of the landing page more reliable now for getting the session code?

Comment: For code 307 it says the request should be repeated with anther URI, how would I get hold of the new URI ie the one that I need to repeat the request with (which would be pretty similar to the old one except that it would not include a session code). I could hard code bits of it and build it up but I'd rather not.

Comment: @user2834566 The redirect URL is in the `Location` header. It will give you the same URL as the one contained in the HTML page.

Comment: Edit: My last comment should say  (which would be pretty similar to the old one except that it **would** include a session code). not that it **would not** - typo!